# Why doesn't the capacitor fill to the maximum?

Tags: capacitor, charging, transient

I am comparing a simulation and a real experiment I did in which my capacitor didn't fill all the way.

The capacitor I used is 10 μF with a 1 kΩ resistor with a 12 V source. I have both graphs:

[image]

This is a sumulation using MultiSim.

[image]

This is a real experiment I did.

Comment: The simulation assumes ideal measurement conditions, while the experiment involves a real-world oscilloscope probe. The resistance of the probe appears to load the circuit appreciably, preventing the capacitor from charging to 12 V as in the ideal case.

Comment: Sounds imposaible, but what aspects you are not telling? If you omit the capacitor, does it go to 12V? If yes, faulty capacitor. If voltage goes to same lower DC value, something in the circuit causes it.

Comment: Try 2V/Div, your signal is outside the range of the scope.

Comment: Does y our scope read 12V if you connect directly across the supply?

Comment: Surely you can double check with a multimeter?

Comment: @PhilFreedenberg Stack Exchange was created to get rid of guesses that can't be vetted by the community. You should leave your answers in the answer section.

Comment: That curve doesn't look like a `1-exp(-x)` to me. There's something else going on in there. Actually, it looks like the axes are interchanged: X is vertical and Y horizontal... Does anyone else see this?

Answer (score 20):

You've likely exceeded dynamic range of CH1, making measurements untrustworthy.
Notice that the "zero" indicator for CH1 (lower left corner) is pointing down, indicating that the *real zero* for CH1 is off-screen. Normally, you'd like to see the indicator pointing to the right, which means that **CH1 zero** is on-screen.
You'd like to see the whole rise from zero volts up to +12v on-screen. To do that, you'd want to change to 2V/div, rather than the 1V/div set currently. Then the whole rise would take 6 divisions.

Why do the on-screen measurements give you wrong results?
 Simply overload of the oscilloscope's internal amplifiers. The amplifiers can likely handle waves that exceed screen boundaries by a small amount. How much overscale the amplifiers can handle is often not specified.

[image: exceeded dynamic range of RIGOL CH1]

Answer (score 0):

There are many factors which could make the voltage appear lower, it really depends on the setup and how the measurement is made. Cable resistance can cut back on the amount of voltage that the capacitor sees. Another problem is grounding and where the ground of the oscilloscope is placed.

One thing you may want to try is putting a scope probe on the bottom and top of the cap and then measuring the voltage. Also see if there are any potentials across the wires.